Can a subset of $\mathbb R$ of size $\aleph_1$ be explicitly constructed?
The Continuum Hypothesis claims that $|\mathbb R|=\aleph_1$. This has already been proven unprovable within ZFC. However, we can prove within ZFC that $|\mathbb R|\ge\aleph_1$ and thus there exists $S\subset\mathbb R$ such that $|S| = \aleph_1$. Can such a set be explicitly constructed?
The most naive approach for this problem would consist in looking for a subset of $\mathbb R$ isomorphic to $\omega_1$, but one can easily show there is no such (because $\mathbb R$ contains a countable dense subset).
I understand some provable things within ZFC can not be explicitly constructed, e.g. propositions that require the axiom of choice, such as a good ordering for $\mathbb R$. Is this the case for such a set?

What do you mean by explicit in this case? Without the axiom of choice, we cannot exhibit such a set. With the axiom of choice, yes, we can, in terms of a parameter (a well-ordering, or an appropriate choice function).

I (?!) reopened the question; since the discussion is in the context of ZFC, it is not explicitly about whether witnesses can be found without the axiom of choice.

The basic strategy of an earlier answer of Asaf Karagila's can be used here too to show that there is no formula $\varphi$ which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves defines a set of reals of size $\aleph_1$. (Really, one proves: if $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\varphi(x)\}$ is uncountable then there is a forcing extension in which that set has size continuum.) The details are a bit technical, but I suspect this is folklore.
This, combined with the usual descriptive set theoretic obstacles (assuming $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ there is no Borel set of size $\aleph_1$, nor a projective set of size $\aleph_1$ if there are also large cardinals), gives a pretty strong negative answer.
Beyond this, you will need to make more precise your notion of "explicit construction."
